# Why isn't Google Chrome rendering this webpage?

Tags: google-chrome

Said webpage: http://www.portugalpoker.net/

All major browsers open and render this website.
I've tested it on Windows and OSX with IE, Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

Chrome loads the webpage (you can see the source and it also fetches all javascript and css files), but doesn't display it.

Did I code anything wrong?

Comment: The red color is hurting my eyes. Please consider changing the UI color.

Comment: your site is perfectly open'd  here at my place and ofcourse in chrome..

Comment: Confirmed in Chrome 7. The first thing I would try is remove all Javascript

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.portugalpoker.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 2):

That is weird! It does load the source, however, when you look at it with the Dev Tools, all you have is

```
<html>
   <head>...</head>
   <style>...{ visibility:hidden !important;    display:none !important; }</style>
</html>
```

And in the Resources tab you have "Failed to load resource"

So I'd start by looking at that!

Comment: Yes, "Failed to load resource". Must be a Chrome bug.